# GDAL (Python) reduce raster by systematic sampling

Tags: python, raster, gdal

Is there any way to reduce a gdal raster in Python by sampling e.g. every 5th cell in both longitude and latitude directions?

The methods supported by gdal (e.g. [gdalwarp](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html#cmdoption-gdalwarp-r), [Rescale raster to custom resolution using sum as the function to aggregate](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/317129)) don't appear to support this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rasterio can do this: https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resampling.html#up-and-downsampling

Code copied from link:

```py
import rasterio
from rasterio.enums import Resampling

upscale_factor = 1/5

with rasterio.open("example.tif") as dataset:

    # resample data to target shape
    data = dataset.read(
        out_shape=(
            dataset.count,
            int(dataset.height * upscale_factor),
            int(dataset.width * upscale_factor)
        ),
        resampling=Resampling.bilinear
    )

    # scale image transform
    transform = dataset.transform * dataset.transform.scale(
        (dataset.width / data.shape[-1]),
        (dataset.height / data.shape[-2])
    )
```