# Systematic sample of gdal raster and output to tif

Tags: python, gdal, numpy, rasterio

I need to sample a raster from a geotif and output the result to a new tif file.  [This answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/360398/gdal-python-reduce-raster-by-systematic-sampling/360399#360399) (from @snowman2 to [GDAL (Python) reduce raster by systematic sampling](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/360398/115)) may have got me some of the way, but I'm still struggling.  Here's a reproducible workflow:

```
import numpy
import gdal
import rasterio
from rasterio.enums import Resampling

file = 'ftp://ftp.worldpop.org.uk/GIS/Population/Global_2000_2020/2020/BMU/bmu_ppp_2020_UNadj.tif'

# sytematic sampling of a raster (1 in 5 cells in both longitude and latitude directions)
upscale_factor = 1/5

with rasterio.open(file) as dataset:
    # resample data to target shape
    data = dataset.read(
        out_shape=(
            dataset.count,
            int(dataset.height * upscale_factor),
            int(dataset.width * upscale_factor)
        ),
        resampling=Resampling.bilinear
    )

    # scale image transform
    transform = dataset.transform * dataset.transform.scale(
        (dataset.width / data.shape[-1]),
        (dataset.height / data.shape[-2])
    )

# rebuild the output object
ds = gdal.Open(file)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
arr = band.ReadAsArray()
[cols, rows] = arr.shape
arr_min = arr.min()
arr_max = arr.max()
arr_mean = int(arr.mean())
arr_out = numpy.where((arr < arr_mean), -99999, arr)
driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")

# get geo metadata from original
outdata = driver.Create("bmu_ppp_2020_UNadj-sampled.tif", rows, cols, 1, gdal.GDT_UInt16)
outdata.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())     ## sets same geotransform as input
outdata.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())         ## sets same projection as input
outdata.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(arr_out)
outdata.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(-99999)   ## if you want these values transparent
outdata.FlushCache()                              ## saves to disk
outdata = None
```

The resulting tif has 3 problems:

1. it is not sampled but retains the dimensions of the original
2. the float values have been changed to integers
3. the missing values have been assigned to 0 despite the `SetNoDataValue` step

R can run this full read-sample-write process in 3 lines, but our production workflow requires Python so I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Cracked it. Possibly still some tweaks required, but the following changes seems to work:

1. `arr` defined by `data[0]` instead of `band.ReadAsArray()`
2. `gdal.GDT_UInt16` changes to `gdal.GDT_Float32`

```
import numpy
import gdal
import rasterio
from rasterio.enums import Resampling
from os import chdir

chdir('xxx')
file = 'ftp://ftp.worldpop.org.uk/GIS/Population/Global_2000_2020/2020/BMU/bmu_ppp_2020_UNadj.tif'

# sytematic sampling of a raster
scale_factor = 5

with rasterio.open(file) as dataset:
    # resample data to target shape
    data = dataset.read(
        out_shape=(
            dataset.count,
            int(dataset.height * 1/scale_factor),
            int(dataset.width * 1/scale_factor)
        ),
        resampling=Resampling.bilinear
    )

    # scale image transform
    transform = dataset.transform * dataset.transform.scale(
        (dataset.width / data.shape[-1]),
        (dataset.height / data.shape[-2])
    )

# original tif metadata
ds = gdal.Open(file)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
arr = data[0]              # changed
[cols, rows] = arr.shape
arr_min = arr.min()
arr_max = arr.max()
arr_mean = int(arr.mean())
# arr_out = numpy.where((arr < arr_mean), -99999, arr)
arr_out = arr

driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
outdata = driver.Create("bmu_ppp_2020_UNadj-sampled.tif", arr.shape[1], arr.shape[0], 1, gdal.GDT_Float32)  # changed
outdata.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())     ## sets same geotransform as input
outdata.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())         ## sets same projection as input
outdata.GetRasterBand(1).WriteArray(arr_out)
outdata.GetRasterBand(1).SetNoDataValue(-99999)   ## if you want these values transparent
outdata.FlushCache()                              ## saves to disk
outdata = None
```